# Compiling haskell module Network on win32/cygwin

Tags: networking, haskell

I am trying to compile Network.HTTP (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/network) on win32/cygwin. However, it does fail with following message:

```
Setup.hs: Missing dependency on a foreign library:
* Missing (or bad) header file: HsNet.h
This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
--extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.
If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
```

Unfortuntely it does not give more clues. The HsNet.h includes sys/uio.h which, actually should not be included, and should be configurered correctly.

Comment: Your post says Network.HTTP but your url and reference are to the Network package.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use cygwin, instead follow [Johan Tibells](http://blog.johantibell.com/search?updated-max=2011-02-21T19:01:00-08:00&max-results=7&start=28&by-date=false) way

Installing MSYS

```
Install the latest Haskell Platform. Use the default settings.

Download version 1.0.11 of MSYS. You'll need the following files:
    MSYS-1.0.11.exe
    msysDTK-1.0.1.exe
    msysCORE-1.0.11-bin.tar.gz

The files are all hosted on haskell.org as they're quite hard to find in the official MinGW/MSYS repo.

Run MSYS-1.0.11.exe followed by msysDTK-1.0.1.exe. The former asks you if you want to run a normalization step. You can skip that.

Unpack msysCORE-1.0.11-bin.tar.gz into C:\msys\1.0. Note that you can't do that using an MSYS shell, because you can't overwrite the files in use, so make a copy of C:\msys\1.0, unpack it there, and then rename the copy back to C:\msys\1.0.

Add C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\VERSION\mingw\bin to your PATH. This is neccesary if you ever want to build packages that use a configure script, like network, as configure scripts need access to a C compiler.
```

These steps are what Tibell uses to compile the Network package for win and I have used this myself successfully several times on most of the haskell platform releases.

Comment: I used successfully MSYS2 for network compilation, too.

Comment: Here are some good practices (including MSYS2 installing):
https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Windows

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to build network on win32/cygwin. And the above steps, though useful (by Jonke) may not be necessary.

While doing the configuration step, specify

```
runghc Setup.hs configure  --configure-option="--build=mingw32"
```

So that the library is configured for mingw32, else you will get link or "undefined references" if you try to link or use network library.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/libraries/2010-January/012968.html) combined with @Yogesh Sajanikar's answer made it work for me (on win64/cygwin):

> - Make sure the gcc on your path is NOT the Mingw/Cygwin one, but the
>     C:\ghc\ghc-6.12.1\mingw\bin\gcc.exe

(Run

```
export PATH="/cygdrive/.../ghc-7.8.2/mingw/bin:$PATH"
```

before running `cabal install network` in the Cygwin shell)