# Cannot install my Hakyll blog on Windows (issue with network library)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, hakyll

My Ubuntu laptop is dead. So I'm trying to install the Haskell projects for my [Hakyll blog](https://github.com/stla/hakyllsource) on Windows. I didn't change anything to the source code and the **stack.yaml** file, and I installed the Haskell platform. The library **network** fails to compile. When I do

```
stack install network
```

I get these error messages:

```
network> * Missing (or bad) header file: HsNet.h
network> This problem can usually be solved by installing the system package that
network> provides this library (you may need the "-dev" version). If the library is
network> already installed but in a non-standard location then you can use the flags
network> --extra-include-dirs= and --extra-lib-dirs= to specify where it is.If the
network> library file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
network> compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
network> with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
network> If the header file does exist, it may contain errors that are caught by the C
network> compiler at the preprocessing stage. In this case you can re-run configure
network> with the verbosity flag -v3 to see the error messages.
network>

--  While building package network-3.1.1.1 (scroll up to its section to see the error) using:
      C:\Users\sdl96354\AppData\Local\Temp\stack-8431997fcaa12db3\network-3.1.1.1\.stack-work\dist\29cc6475\setup\setup --builddir=.stack-work\dist\29cc6475 configure --with-ghc=C:\Users\sdl96354\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.4\bin\ghc-8.8.4.exe --with-ghc-pkg=C:\Users\sdl96354\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\ghc-8.8.4\bin\ghc-pkg.exe --user --package-db=clear --package-db=global --package-db=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\pkgdb --libdir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\lib --bindir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\bin --datadir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\share --libexecdir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\libexec --sysconfdir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\etc --docdir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\doc\network-3.1.1.1 --htmldir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\doc\network-3.1.1.1 --haddockdir=C:\sr\snapshots\ce41ca4b\doc\network-3.1.1.1 --dependency=base=base-4.13.0.0 --dependency=bytestring=bytestring-0.10.10.1 --dependency=deepseq=deepseq-1.4.4.0 --extra-include-dirs=C:\Users\sdl96354\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20210604\mingw64\include --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\sdl96354\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20210604\mingw64\lib --extra-lib-dirs=C:\Users\sdl96354\AppData\Local\Programs\stack\x86_64-windows\msys2-20210604\mingw64\bin --exact-configuration --ghc-option=-fhide-source-paths
    Process exited with code: ExitFailure 1
```

I don't know what should I do and I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error states that you are missing some system library, which is a dependency of haskell [network package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/network).

So you can either learn about [how haskell stack works on Windows](https://wiki.haskell.org/Windows) and look at [questions about compilation of network package on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078997/compiling-haskell-module-network-on-win32-cygwin), or you can just install some GNU/Linux distribution as a virtual machine and work as usual.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Cabal now. It is slow... or is it Windows?..